# How to install wireless drivers via USB?

Tags: wifi

I just installed elementary on my new laptop besides the Windows 10 boot it came with. Problem now is, wireless connectivity isn't working. After looking into multiple threads regarding the problem, I've figured it's probably missing drivers.

The thing is though, this laptop has no ethernet port. Is there anyway to install the drivers via an USB flash drive? Can anyone with experience help out?

lspci: `Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device b822`

Comment: The driver is part of the kernel. What's your kernel version? Check it with `uname -r` . You can try to disable secureboot from the firmware/bios. It's known that it causes issues.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/q/1057900) the chip should be supported by Ubuntu 18.04, which is the basis of elementary OS 5.0 Juno. If disabling secureboot does not work, you can try to install the packages described there by [using apt-mirror](https://askubuntu.com/a/1043), which allows you to load packages onto a USB drive.